# Where is this encryption/decryption algorithm going wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm, encryption

I've been working on a basic string encryption/decryption algorithm in C++ (the source is here: http://pastebin.com/MLnn8D82)

The problem I'm having is that it doesn't decrypt properly. The encryption equation is:

```
strInput[nPos]=(((strInput[nPos])+(nPos+1))*2);
```

And the decryption equation is:

```
strPassword[nPos]=(((strPassword[nPos])-(nPos+1))/2);
```

When I try it with just addition/subtraction operators, it works perfectly. But when I multiply in encryption and divide in decryption, I get a seemingly random string outputted.

At first I thought it may be because the password is written to and retrieved from a file before being decrypted, but I tried outputting it directly from the main function and I ended up with the same results.

Is there a problem with dividing/multiplying strings? It worked before with C-style (char array) strings, but I guess this could be different.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Thanks for the answers so far. I know that this isn't secure and that I shouldn't use it; I'm only doing it for practice.

Also, it's not a memory problem. I've tried dividing in the encryption stage rather than multiplying, but I still get a random string rather than the original string.

Comment: What happens if that calculation results in a value that is bigger than what a char can hold?

Comment: You already wen wrong by creating your own algorithm instead of using a standard algorithm.

Answer (score 8):

It's quite likely your multiplication is overflowing for some characters, meaning your division will never be able to recover the original.

On a side note, why are you writing the encryption algorithm yourself? If you're going to be using it for anything real, rather than just learning, you would be much better off using a library written by cryptography experts that is known to be secure. Something like [Keyczar](http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/) would be a good idea because it's designed to be difficult to get wrong (which is very easy to do in ways that are very subtle when it comes to cryptography).

Comment: Sorry I just noticed I was in C++ side

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with this algorithm:

1. This is just a basic change to a standard [Vigenère Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), which is well known to be very insecure. Do not use it for anything more than writing letters to a girlfriend, which other students should not be able to read. Even a somewhat decent math teacher will be able to decipher it easily.
2. Do not ever try to invent a cryptographic algorithm, unless you have a doctorate in number theory or cryptography. Even with a degree in one of these fields, writing a cryptographic algorithm, which is fairly secure, is a very hard task. And even if you find an algorithm, do not try to implement it yourself, but rather try to find an implementation which is already available. There is a lot you can get wrong, as can be seen by the various security flaws, which were cause by badly implemented cryptographic algorithms.
3. You do not have any support for a passphrase in your algorithm. This means, anybody who knows the algorithm can easily decipher your encrypted data. Usually a cryptographic algorithm takes a passphrase as an input, which is then used to decipher the data. This way the algorithm can be made public and only the passphrase must be kept secret. If the algorithm is kept secret, this is considered a fatal flaw by the cryptographic community.
4. Your multiplication might overflow, in case it yields a result, which is bigger than what could be stored in a char. In that case a division will not be able to retrieve the original data. This has been pointed out by others as well.
5. The order of operation is wrong. In your encryption step you add first then you multiply. Have a look at the resultion equation. Solving that equation for the input means you also have to change the order. In your case this means, you first have to divide and then you have to subtract. However in your code you are first subtracting and then dividing.

These are all the things I can tell you for now. This is not meant to discourage you from trying out this kind of stuff. I wrote a fair amount of similar algorithms when I was much younger. You just need to be very aware, that they will not be very secure.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

One appears to stem from the use of strings and the input/output streams. If you set a breakpoint and step through this you'll realize that in the `fRetrieve` function the values of `strPassword[nPos]` can be negative. You are essentially reading in binary data into a string and trying to act on it.

What you should be doing is processing your strings into a binary data buffer. Such as a char array. That solely stores bytes. Then in your decryption you will get purely binary data back and can convert that into a string. This will insure the integrity of your data when writing/reading from the file. Playing with strings and high ASCII values is asking for the data to be interpreted wrong.

Second, is that your decryption algorithm is not properly reversed. So even if you did decrypt it correctly you would be off by 1 every time. This is an order of operations issue.

Example, assume an A (65) and `nPos` of 0. Encrypt:

```
65 + (0+1) = 66 * 2 = 132
```

Then reverse:

```
132 - (0+1) = 131 / 2 = 65.5
```

This may be rounded or truncated since it's an integer data type. The proper reverse is

```
(strPassword[nPos] / 2) - (nPos+1)
```